# Docker ARGs don't get substituted in docker file

Tags: java, docker

I'm trying to use ARG inside docker file but it doesn't work, I'm a newbie

Here is my docker file

```
 ARG appver=0.0.1
 ENV ausername=any
 COPY ./target/userservice-${appver}-SNAPSHOT.jar .
 CMD  ["java", "-jar", "userservice-${appver}-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

so, when I build the image I expected the jar name to be

```
 userservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

but what I get is

```
Step 9/10 : COPY ./target/userservice-${appver}-SNAPSHOT.jar .
---> 3f2772c50130
Step 10/10 : CMD  ["java", "-jar", "userservice-${appver}-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
---> Running in 47286088595a
```

Answer (score 2):

Docker doesn't expand build args in the CMD step. You'll want to do two things. First, copy your build arg into an environment variable. And second, switch to the shell syntax to expand that environment variable.

```
ARG appver=0.0.1
ENV ausername=any
ENV appver=${appver}
COPY ./target/userservice-${appver}-SNAPSHOT.jar .
CMD exec java -jar userservice-${appver}-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I added an exec to get rid of the shell from pid 1 as soon as it expands the command. This aids in signal handling.

Comment: Thank you.  can you also explain why it didn't work with the 'COPY' statement?

Comment: @HeshamOsman why do you believe it didn't work in the COPY? The build didn't error on that step. Have you checked the contents of the image?

Comment: I assumed that from the logs.                                      \n Step 9/10 : COPY ./target/userservice-${appver}-SNAPSHOT.jar .
---> 3f2772c50130